# Codeigniter: Using session to call another table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Basically I have 3 tables.

1. Users with userID [PK], password
2. Skills with skillsID [PK], skillsName
3. UserSkills with userID [FK], skillsID [FK]

Using session that reads user data (login) from Users table, I want to display skillsName from Skills table.

Is it possible?

Comment: Seems possible. What have you tried so far? Try reading codeigniter.com documentation on Sessions, you will get a good idea about it and if you still are not able to resolve it, ask here

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#adding-session-data

Answer (score 0):

set userdata

```
 $this->session->set_userdata('some_name', 'some_value');
```

if you want to verify that a session value exists

```
// returns FALSE if the 'some_name' item doesn't exist or is NULL,
// TRUE otherwise:
isset($_SESSION['some_name'])
```

or

```
$this->session->has_userdata('some_name');
```